# How to read/write from file, In Portable Class Library (dll)?

Tags: vb.net, file, dll, vb.net-2010

I am build a dll called TdlElement in vb.net.

One of the functions in that class need to write a string to file (I have the full file name and the string), well in Windows form application or Console  application project I can use -

```
  Public Sub WriteToFile(ByVal Filename As String, ByVal MainText As String)
    Dim sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Filename)
    sw.Write(MainText)
    sw.Close()
  End Sub
```

but in Portable Class Library project (dll) I dont have a constructor for StreamWriter with string, In addition I dont have System.IO.File Class.
And I have the same problem for reading from file.

So how can I read/write to files from a code in dll (Portable Class Library Project) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can't be done in a PCL.  You will have to rewrite your method to accept a `Stream` and then pass that to the `StreamWriter` constructor.  You can then create an appropriate `Stream` in whatever app is using the library, e.g. a `FileStream` in Windows Forms.